# NSMutableArray getting released before ViewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my header file I have:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * array1;
```

and in My `initWithNibName` method I have:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

    self.array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test", nil];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(DoUpdateLabel:) name:@"DoUpdateLabel" object:nil];

}
return self;
}
```

The `DoUpdateLable` method does some updating to the array (adds a number of items). Once this is complete and ViewDidLoad executes my array disappears and becomes null which is annoying because I want to load it into a table view.

Here's a trimmed down version of the `DoUpdateLable` method. I've had to trim it down as the actual method includes a lot of JSON parsing and URL requests:

```
-(void)DoUpdateLabel:(NSNotification *) notification
{   
int count = 0;
while(count < 59)
{
    NSString * currentpatname = @"test1";
    if(![currentpatname isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [self.array1 addObject:currentpatname];
        NSLog(@"array: %@", self.array1);
    }
    count++;
}

NSLog(@"final array: %@", self.array1);
}
```

I'm a little stuck as to why it's not being retained. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your updated question, you're setting up that array inside the scope that starts with `// Custom initialization`. But what you don't notice is that `viewDidLoad` is actually called on this line:
`self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];`

That means your array is still nil inside viewDidLoad, and thus `DoUpdateLabel`

I would recommend instead initializing that array inside `-viewDidLoad` instead, and you'll see the results you're looking for.

Comment: This doesn't really address the problem so far.

Comment: Tried it. It made no difference to the problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Adam Then there is an additional problem you're not showing us. But as far as what code you initially showed, that was indeed part of the problem.

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question. In viewdidload if I do: NSLog(@"viewloadarray: %@", self.array1); it returns null.

Comment: What you're saying here is all wrong. Referring to the array with _array1 does not have any effect on whether the array is retained or not (in fact, inside an init method, it's better to use _array1). Also, viewDidLoad is not called in the init method.

Comment: @rdelmar Correct, he has changed his code quite a bit since initial posting, and I've subsequently edited my answer. It's now clear what the issue is and I've edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: @rdelmar And yes viewDidLoad can be called if super is not nil, and he's accessed the view from inside that superclass's init method.

Comment: Yes, if he's accessed the view from the superclass's init method, that would be true, but there's no indication that he's done that (I'm guessing that the superclass is probably UITableViewController or UIViewController).

Comment: @rdelmar Can you think of any other reason that it would be nil in viewDidLoad? I think we still need more info from him then. :(

Comment: The problem is that DoUpdateLabel gets called before viewDidLoad and as such if I don't initialise the array in initWithNibName it is simply equal to Null until I initialise the array in viewDidLoad at which point it simply contains "test". The DoUpdateLabel definitely gets called before viewDidLoad as I've checked with break points. And indeed the superclass is a UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

initWithNibName:bundle: is called if you just use alloc init somewhere. You probably have done that, but you shouldn't be. Delete that, and put the code you have in your question in initWithCoder:, then it should work properly.